# Tailwind transition is not working in Nextjs component

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

The ease out transition is not working. I want the side to appear from left to right with a duration of 500ms. I've tried quite a bit of things but can't figure out why is it not working. While examining in dev tool, the transition class is being attached properly but the effect doesn't show up. Here is my code

```
    "use client"
import Image from "next/image"
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import profile from '../../assets/images/profile.png'
import { buttonprops } from "@/data/Data";
import NavLinks from "./NavLinks/NavLinks";
import { ButtonType } from "@/types/button";
import { faBars } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";


const Navbar = () => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
    const toggleVisibility = () => {
        console.log("item is being clicked and vlaue of visibie is " + isVisible)
        setIsVisible(!isVisible);
    };
    const handleMouseClick = () => {
        if (isVisible) {
            setIsVisible(!isVisible);
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row">
            <div className={`flex border border-black `}>
                <div className="flex row border border-black md:hidden">
                    <div className="flex w-44 h-14 border items-center border-black pl-4">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className="text-3xl" onClick={toggleVisibility} icon={faBars} />

                    </div>
                </div>
```

// ${isVisible ? 'absolute transition w-80 duration-300 ease-in-out' : 'hidden'}
// Here i am conditionally adding the classes hidden

```
                <div className={`md:block w-44 h-screen border border-black text-white ${isVisible ? 'absolute transition w-80 duration-300 ease-in-out' : 'hidden'} `}>

                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center pt-5 pb-10 border bg-slate-200">
                        <Image src={profile} width={500} height={500} className="rounded-full w-32 h-32 border-4  border-blue-500" alt="Picture of the author" />
                    </div>

                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#222e50' }} className="flex flex-col h-full ">
                        {buttonprops.map((data, i) => {
                            return <NavLinks key={i} name={data.name} icon={data.icon} />;
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div onClick={handleMouseClick} className="border border-black w-full h-screen">
                <div className="flex border h-14 w-full border-black items-center justify-center md:hidden">
                    <div className="hi"> Data </div>
                </div>
                <div className="w-full">
                    Content
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the transition class conditionally, as it will not kick in simultaneously with the changed styles.

```html
<div className={`md:block w-44 h-screen border border-black text-white transition ${isVisible ? 'absolute w-80 duration-300 ease-in-out' : 'hidden'} `}>
...
</div>
```